# How do I pull a dotenv file in as a pkg asset?

Tags: node.js, npm, vercel, dotenv

I need to get some dotenv data I have tried to use assets but it returns undefined if I leave the folder with the .env the asset glob I used is:

```json
  "pkg": {
    "assets": ".env",
  }
```

I execute pkg with `pkg .` and my bin entry is setup as is.

```json
  "bin": {
    "bot":"./src/bot.js"
  }
```